# How do I give multiple objects with different sizes the same texture resolution?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

how do I give multiple objects with different sizes the same texture resolution?

If I simple unwrap the objects, I get the result that some objects have a sharp texture and some not.

thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you texturing it, under what render engine, Cycles or Blender Internal? If you don't specifically need unwrapping you could use procedural texture coordinates like *Object* texture coordinates if they all have applied scale or with an additional *Vector Transform* node if they don't.

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of your material node setup? We can probably make some useful suggestions based on that.  ^_^

Comment: I added a picture!